# Create queue, exchange and binding automatically - Integration Test with qpid Embedded Broker - in JSON file Configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, broker, qpid

I´m trying create a Integration test with qpid embedded memory broker.My idea is to create a component where developers don't have to do any configuration, I want to know if there is a way to create queues, exchanges and bindings automatically from the JSON configuration file. Below show java classes and JSON file configuration.

JSON File configuration: json_config.json

```
{
"name": "Embedded Broker",
"modelVersion": "8.0",
"authenticationproviders": [
    {
        "name": "hardcoded",
        "type": "Plain",
        "secureOnlyMechanisms": [],
        "users": [
            {
                "name": "test",
                "password": "test",
                "type": "managed"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"ports": [
    {
        "name": "AMQP",
        "port": "${qpid.amqp_port}",
        "bindingAddress": "127.0.0.1",
        "protocols": [
            "AMQP_0_9_1"
        ],
        "authenticationProvider": "hardcoded",
        "virtualhostaliases": [
            {
                "name": "defaultAlias",
                "type": "defaultAlias"
            },{
                "name": "nameAlias",
                "type": "nameAlias"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"virtualhostnodes": [
    {
        "name": "localhost",
        "type": "Memory",
        "defaultVirtualHostNode": "true",
        "virtualHostInitialConfiguration" : "{\"type\": \"Memory\",\"context\":{},\"name\":\"localhost\",\"nodeAutoCreationPolicies\":[{\"pattern\":\"[a-z]*.*.queue.test\",\"createdOnPublish\" : true,\"createdOnConsume\" : true,\"nodeType\":\"Queue\" },{\"pattern\":\"[a-z]*.*.exchange.test\",\"createdOnPublish\" : true,\"createdOnConsume\" : false,\"nodeType\":\"exchange\" }]}"
        
    }
]
```

}

In above JSON file, I want declare a queue, exchange and binding in virtualhost part

EmbeddedInMemoryQpidBroker.java

```
public class EmbeddedInMemoryQpidBroker {

private static final String DEFAULT_INITIAL_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION = "rabbit/json_config.json";

private SystemLauncher systemLauncher;

public EmbeddedInMemoryQpidBroker() {
    this.systemLauncher = new SystemLauncher();
}

public void start() throws Exception {
    this.systemLauncher.startup(createSystemConfig());
}

public void shutdown() {
    this.systemLauncher.shutdown();
}

private Map<String, Object> createSystemConfig() throws IllegalConfigurationException {
    Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
    URL initialConfigUrl = EmbeddedInMemoryQpidBroker.class.getClassLoader()
            .getResource(DEFAULT_INITIAL_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION);

    if (initialConfigUrl == null) {
        throw new IllegalConfigurationException(
                "Configuration location '" + DEFAULT_INITIAL_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION + "' not found");
    }
    attributes.put(SystemConfig.TYPE, "Memory");
    attributes.put(SystemConfig.INITIAL_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION, initialConfigUrl.toExternalForm());
    attributes.put(SystemConfig.STARTUP_LOGGED_TO_SYSTEM_OUT, true);
    return attributes;
}
```

}

Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = AuthorizationApplication.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = { "test-rabbit" })
public class StartAuthorizationMessageProducerIntegrationTest {

private static EmbeddedInMemoryQpidBroker brokerStarter;

/* CONSTANTS POPULATION */
private static String HOST = "localhost";

private static String USER = "test";

private static String PASS = "test";

private static String USER_BAD = "user_mal";

private StartAuthorizationMessage authorizationMessagePopulated = new StartAuthorizationMessage("/qpid", "1234",
        "externalId", "CODE");

/* CONSTANTS POPULATION */
@Autowired
@Qualifier("startAuthorizationMessageProducer")
public StartAuthorizationMessageProducer messageProducer;

@Autowired
public RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin;

private String queueName = "queue.test";

private String exchangeName = "exchange.test";

private String routingKey = "routing.test";

@BeforeClass
public static void startup() throws Exception {
    brokerStarter = new EmbeddedInMemoryQpidBroker();
    brokerStarter.start();

}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDown() throws Exception {
    brokerStarter.shutdown();
    ;
}

@Test
public void givenQpidBrokerAndAGoodConnectionThenConnectionIsOpen() throws Exception {

    // given
    Connection connection = null;
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = this.getConnectionFactory(HOST, USER, PASS);
    // when

    connection = connectionFactory.newConnection();

    // then
    assertTrue(connection.isOpen());

}

@Test
public void givenQpidBrokerAndAGoodConnectionWhenPutAMessaggerThenMessageIsQueue() throws Exception {
    // given

    StartAuthorizationMessage messageReturned;

    createQueue();
    createExchange();
    createBinding();
    // when
    messageProducer.sendMessage(authorizationMessagePopulated, null);
    // then
    assertTrue(countMessages() > 0);
    messageReturned = getMessage();
    assertTrue(messageReturned != null);
    assertTrue(messageReturned.getPath().equals(authorizationMessagePopulated.getPath()));
    assertTrue(messageReturned.getId().equals(authorizationMessagePopulated.getId()));
    assertTrue(messageReturned.getExternalAuthorizationId()
            .equals(authorizationMessagePopulated.getExternalAuthorizationId()));
    assertTrue(messageReturned.getOperationCode().equals(authorizationMessagePopulated.getOperationCode()));
    assertTrue(countMessages() == 0);
}

@Test(expected = Exception.class)
public void givenQpidBrokerAndABadConnectionThenConnectionIsClose() throws Exception {

    // given
    Connection connection;
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = this.getConnectionFactory(HOST, USER_BAD, PASS);

    // when

    connection = connectionFactory.newConnection();

    // then
    // exception throws
}

/* Support Methods */

private StartAuthorizationMessage getMessage() throws Exception {

    StartAuthorizationMessage startAuthorizationMessage;
    Message messageAMQP = rabbitAdmin.getRabbitTemplate().receive(queueName);

    String strMessage = new String(messageAMQP.getBody());
    JSONReader jsonReader = new JSONReader();
    HashMap jsonValues = (HashMap)jsonReader.read(strMessage);
    startAuthorizationMessage = new StartAuthorizationMessage((String)jsonValues.get("path"),
            (String)jsonValues.get("id"), (String)jsonValues.get("externalAuthorizationId"),
            (String)jsonValues.get("operationCode"));

    return startAuthorizationMessage;

}

private int countMessages() throws Exception {

    Properties rabbitProperties = rabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(queueName);

    return (int)rabbitProperties.get(RabbitAdmin.QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT);

}

private void createQueue() throws Exception {

    Queue queue = new Queue(queueName);
    rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);

}

private void createExchange() {

    rabbitAdmin.declareExchange(new DirectExchange(exchangeName));
}

private void createBinding() {
    Binding declaredBinding = new Binding(queueName, DestinationType.QUEUE,
            exchangeName, routingKey, null);
    rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(declaredBinding);

}

private ConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory(String host, String userName, String password) throws Exception {

    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setHost(host);
    connectionFactory.setUsername(userName);
    connectionFactory.setPassword(password);

    return connectionFactory;

}
/* Support Methods */
```

}

In test class I´m declare queue, exchange and binding with RabbitAdmin Class, but I want declare it in a JSON config file.

Thank´s for your help.